# how to configure Qt for android

Tags: android, c++, linux, qt, android-ndk

I am using Debian Linux and I want to configure Qt for Android application.
I downloaded Qt from the Qt site and configured JDK, SDK and NDK and gave the path of SDK and NDK path to Qt option, then I restarted Qt creator. But in Debuggers option Qt says:

> /home/user/Qtrequirement/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gdb not exist.

I searched in Google and I found out another NDK at Qt official that has a gdb file but not have every file for NDK. Qt says this is not top level NDK folder.
I googled everything and installed every dependency package that Qt uses.

Can anyone give me any solution that makes apk file and run in any Android device?
FYI any other application that does not use Android will run successfully, but I can not make an apk file using Qt.
Does anyone know the answer for this problem for Debian Linux?

Comment: Take a look on this, i hope it helps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suPeZ7XC1xk

Comment: but this video can not give me launch any android virtual device and make apk file

Comment: Same problem... did you ever resolve this?

Comment: no i change my whole project qt to angular framework that is very good